# How to get next row of MySQL query in php without progressing when using mysqli_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to run a query to my mysql database through php and and am trying to get all the resulting rows. I also have to compare every row to the next row returned. I am trying to do this by setting the result variable to another temporary variable and calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` on that so that the while loop runs again for the next row. But what happens is that when I try to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` even on the other variables, somehow `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` also progresses to the next of the next row when `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` goes to next iteration.

Here is the code example to illustrate this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY num ASC;";
    if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
    {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
         $temporaryresult = $result;
         $rowtwo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($temporaryresult);// this makes mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) skip the next row which is unwanted
       }
    }
```

So how can I keep `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` from moving forward when I call `mysqli_fetch_assoc($temporaryresult)` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this a "behaviour" question? I see `while($row` but you're not using `$row` here, you're using `$rowtwo` as a closest match.

Comment: This is just to show the concept, I am doing a lot with $row in the full code.

Comment: You should write `$result` instead of `$temporaryresult`

Comment: the problem here, is that you're using `mysqli_query()` twice and checking for errors would have thrown you something about it. TBH, I don't know what the question's about and what you want to do here and what the expected results are, compared to what you're getting now.

Comment: and using `$result` too many times.

Comment: someone popped an answer; see that. But I still say you'd be getting an error on `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)
    if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query))` - Edit: to which you just edited out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, saw it. The repetition in the code was a mistake, It isn't there in the real one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @downvoter - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @CBroe's answer, I tried to solve this problem while still trying to look forward. I achieved this by storing the rows returned by the database and then looping through them. This makes it very easy too look ahead in the rows returned while avoiding the complexity of changing your code to look backwards.

```
$array = array(); 
// look through query
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){    
  // add each row returned into an array

  $array[] = $row;

}
```

Now, looping through these rows,

```
$i = 0;
for(;$i<count($array)-1;$i++)
{
   if($array[$i]['somecolumn']==$array[$i+1]['anothercolumn'])//compare this column to another column in the next row
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

This successfully solved my problem. I hope it helps anyone stuck in the same position I was in.

Comment: If you _really_ want to write the code this way, then you can't have the `for` loop running for the full range `$i < count($array)`. In the last iteration, `$array[$i]['somecolumn']` would point to the last element in the array, which means `$array[$i+1]['anothercolumn']` would actually point to an index which doesn't even exist. I don't know how / why it worked without throwing any errors for you, but if it did, then please know that it's only a matter of chance. If you `echo $array[$i+1]['anothercolumn']`, it would certainly show something unexpected (including nothing).

Comment: @DhruvSaxena - Edited the answer in response to your comment. Should work fine now.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, it should be safe now :)

Answer (score 3):

> am trying to do this by setting the result variable to another temporary variable and calling mysqli_fetch_assoc() on that so that the while loop runs again for the next row

It doesn’t work that way. Just because you assigned the resource id to a second variable, doesn’t mean that you now have a second result set that you could operate on separately. Both variables refer to the same resource id. Fetching a row will still move the row pointer of the “original” data set.

> I also have to compare every row to the next row returned

Most likely, you are making things harder on yourself by trying to look ahead. Stuff like this is usually easier done when you look at the *previous* row instead. That one you *have* fetched already - so you don’t need to do an additional fetch now that would mess with the row pointer.

Pseudo code example:

```
$prevRow = null;
while($row = fetch(...)) {
  if($prevRow) { // for the first row, this will still be null, so we only 
                 // start comparing stuff when that is not the case
    // compare whatever you need to compare here
  }
  ...
  $prevRow = $row;
}
```

Comment: Good Idea!, sometimes we have to do the opposite to get the result we want.

Comment: Doing this will miss the last element in the array.